# External hard drive isn't allowing file removal or cuting of files or folders

Tags: permissions, hard-drive

The folders won't allowing any editing and I can't add any new files onto the external hard drive despite the fact that there is space, and when attempting to access the permissions of the drive I am hit with this error message

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbaXa.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have a read-only file system. You can only read files from it, not write to it.

Lacking more information, I will make an educated guess that that external drive is formatted using the ntfs file system of MS Windows. If that is not clean, then Linux will mount it read-only to prevent further damage to the file system. That could explain the behavior you see.

To resolve the issue, connect the drive to a Windows system, and have the partition checked using the Windows disk checking tools. Once the file system is repaired and consistent, it will mount with read and write permissions in Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you I'll give this a try (it has been working on other linux systems in the past however and it was only when I've run it on this setup that it's given me the error) 

I appreciate the effort :)

Comment: Thank you! That sorted it cheers

Comment: If it did, then please "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark next to the question.